# Laravel all DB tables deleted?

Tags: sql, laravel

Quite angry right now.
Created a new Migration in Laravel, ran `migrate:rollback`, but suddently all of my db files have been deleted - and I have no backup.

Every time I migrate bad stuff happens...
Laravel is great, but currently everything is gone.

Any idea?

I need help.

Thanks.

Comment: "all of my db files" what "db files"?

Answer (score 0):

From de [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#rolling-back-migrations)...

> To rollback the latest migration operation, you may use the rollback
>   command. **This command rolls back the last "BATCH" of migrations, which
>   may include MULTIPLE migration files**:

You may rollback a **limited number of migrations** by providing the **step** option to the rollback command.

`php artisan migrate:rollback --step=5` will rollback the last five migrations:

Comment: Sure. But when I executed this command, my entire databse disappeared...

Comment: Entire database?? that happened with me because the last batch includes all my migrations, to avoid this kind of things and be sure that you wont loss data my suggestion is always use `--step`